# How to get json specific value registered in Ansible with a loop

Tags: ansible

I'm using ansible uri (rest api) to get info from salesforce specific Case. when i try to register the value i isolated with a loop, it register all the values.

I know the case Id and i want the Case Number associated to the Id :

```
"recentItems": [
        {
            "CaseNumber": "002541154",
            "Id": "500570000D1rhG6qAeE",
        },
        {
            "CaseNumber": "002541329",
            "Id": "5005700001FrhEDJAA2",
        },
        {
            "CaseNumber": "002541438",
            "Id": "5005700001rhE1SSAAU",

        }
```

I can retrieve the Case Number using a loop but when i register it it register all the items

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ json_response.json.recentItems }}"
  when: item.CaseNumber == "00254072"
  register: myCaseNumber
```

The response:

```
ok: [vm-ansible-test] => (item=None) => {
"msg": {
    "CaseNumber": "002554072",
    "Id": "5005700001rgrdSAAAQ",
}
}
```

When i want to show my registered case variable it shows all items:

```
- debug:
    var: myCaseNumber
```

The response:

```
            {
            "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "_ansible_no_log": false,
            "changed": false,
            "item": {
                "CaseNumber": "002540946",
                "Id": "5005700001rgwLGAAAY"
            },
            "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False",
            "skipped": true
        },
        {
            "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "_ansible_no_log": false,
            "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
            "changed": false,
            "failed": false,
            "item": {
                "CaseNumber": "002554072",
                "Id": "5005700001rgrdSAAAQ"
            },
            "msg": {
                "CaseNumber": "002554072",
                "Id": "5005700001rgrdSAAAQ"
            }
        },
        {
            "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "_ansible_no_log": false,
            "changed": false,
            "item": {
                "CaseNumber": "002515455",
                "Id": "5005700001qa62MEAAQ"
            },
            "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False",
            "skipped": true
        }
```

So how can i register only the value i need ?

i surely should not the first asking this but i searched with many different terms and tried different ways but i didnt succeed to make this work...

Comment: Besides the most voted answer under the dup-target gives you a better approach, `debug` module is not for setting values, `set_fact` is.

Comment: It works ! thx 

my code: 
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ json_response.json | json_query(\"recentItems[?CaseNumber=='002554072'].Id\") }}